# Is this an Electron BrowserWindow bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, electron

I coded a product aggregator for Amazon. I collect products from amazon with proxies. Before the BrowserWindow occurs in Electron, there is no problem when I send a request with a proxy. But when I make a request after the BrowserWindow is created, the captcha pops up, and it cannot collect any products. I am using Nklayman's Vue CLI and electron builder. I used axios, node-fetch and finally got as the request library. But they all have the same problem. Any ideas as to why?

**Before BrowserWindow:**

```
async function createWindow() {
   let api = new AmazonApi({
      domain: 'com',
      country: 'CA'
   });

   await api.initialize();
   await api.grab.search('https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A193870011&ref=nav_em__nav_desktop_sa_intl_computer_components_0_2_6_3');

   const win = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 800,
      height: 600
   })

   createProtocol('app')
   win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
}
```

**Output**

```
Anti-CSRF Token => SUCCESS
get-rendered-toaster => SUCCESS
gp/product/sessionCache => SUCCESS
CSRF Token => SUCCESS
ajax/address-change => SUCCESS
Change Country => SUCCESS
District => Canada
```

**After BrowserWindow:**

```
async function createWindow() {
   const win = new BrowserWindow({
     width: 800,
     height: 600
   })

   let api = new AmazonApi({
      domain: 'com',
      country: 'CA'
   });

   await api.initialize();
   await api.grab.search('https://www.amazon.com/s?i=specialty-aps&bbn=16225007011&rh=n%3A16225007011%2Cn%3A193870011&ref=nav_em__nav_desktop_sa_intl_computer_components_0_2_6_3');

   createProtocol('app')
   win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
}
```

**Output**

```
CAPTCHA DETECTED ->https://www.amazon.com/
@ Captcha solving...
C:\Users\orcun\Desktop\amazon-proxy-fix\test-app\captcha_solver.exe
=> CAPTCHA: MGBUTG
=> IMG: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/captcha/dgbcpgrn/Captcha_kjlvdsmekc.jpg
validateCaptcha => SUCCESS
get-rendered-toaster => SUCCESS
gp/product/sessionCache => SUCCESS
CAPTCHA FINISHED
/ah/ajax/counter?ctr=desktop_ajax_atf&exp=1659983037410&rId=NB8M5RMTWB1NVAMSHKQ1&mkId=ATVPDKIKX0DER&h=8f80016a7d247f396ae96dc5c9f174f474fba2993aed7ca95eb27e2f0986abde
Anti-CSRF Token => SUCCESS
get-rendered-toaster => SUCCESS
gp/product/sessionCache => SUCCESS
get-rendered-toaster => SUCCESS
gp/product/sessionCache => SUCCESS
Failed to get Csrf Token
```

**Screenshots:**

[Before BrowserWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deJLJ.png)

[After BrowserWindow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTmll.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question: Never, **ever** post images of code or log messages, but instead include them as text! Thanks

Comment: Also, this could be just about anything and I don't think the `BrowserWindow` could be related to it. Is the error popping up reliably or only in x% of the cases?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner There's a whole problem. I know it's silly, but before BrowserWindow, the API I wrote for Amazon with proxy works fine. But when I try to collect products with API after BrowserWindow, all proxies have problems and I cannot collect products.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I updated the topic in the structure you requested. Thanks for your alert. Any idea about the problem?

Comment: So this `AmazonApi` thingy is something you've written and not something official? That might be the root of the whole problem and CAPTCHAs are usually there for a reason. Anyhow, I have no clue but it might help others if you could provide code of the relevant functions of your "API" library (through an [edit]). I'm not sure the problem would be reproducible without.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Yes, AmazonApi is a library I coded. But exactly as I described. It works fine before BrowserWindow or in an empty NodeJS project. But the library I wrote does not work after the BrowserWindow is init.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner The library only has HTTP requests to Amazon. How can BrowserWindow break HTTP requests?

Comment: It wouldn't, but Amazon may wonder why a browser connects to pages only a machine accessed before. Maybe put a (fake) `User-Agent` header (Electron's/Chrome's might help...) onto your library's HTTP requests? But I would be very surprised if Electron would make requests to Amazon's infrastructure on its own. To be fair, this is simply guessing at this stage. Is there any reason you need to have your `BrowserWindow` initialise before the API?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I'm sending the request from backend, not electron. I'm using the "got" library for requests. And I'm already using User-Agent in api. So api has nothing to do with electron. After the BrowserWindow is running, the api is broken. It doesn't matter if you start before or after.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner Can I take a video about this situation and share it?

Comment: No, I understand your problem but can only guess because you don't share any code. I have never had this problem in the past and thus *cannot reproduce it*. Here on SO, you're expected to share a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem. Also, you really should make sure that there is no other way of aggregating products from Amazon other than machine-solving CAPTCHAs because this doesn't seem feasible nor right from a TOS point of view. Anyhow, without seeing your code, no-one can tell what screws your state up. If it works before creating the window, why not leave it in this order?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner I solved the problem. Because Electron modifies the http library, Amazon somehow understands that the request is coming from the electron. I solved the problem using this: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/net

Comment: Ya, probably via the `User-Agent` string... If you have solved your problem, please consider adding an answer and accepting it, marking this question as done. Thanks!